# AzureADB2C.UI - Redirect user to page after sign in

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using AzureADB2C.UI on a .NET Core web application but I'm not sure how I can redirect a user to a custom page ej `/Customers/Index` after he signs in.

This is basically what I had previously when using a `SessionController` but I don't have a Controller anymore since I'm using AzureADB2C.UI.

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
properties.Items[AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty] = AzureAdB2COptions.SignUpPolicy;
return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

---

This is what I have on `startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(o => o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme)
   .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureADB2C", options))
   .OnLogin(principal =>
       {
          services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<LoginCommand>()
             .Execute(principal, principal.AzureID(), principal.Email(), principal.DisplayName());
       });
```

`appsettings.json:`

```
"AzureADB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "............", // prod
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "something.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SiUpOrIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_SSPR",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_SiPe"
  }
```

Does anybody knows how to redirect a user after he signs in using AzureADB2C.UI?

Comment: Did you try to set the callback path to the page you want to display after sign in? You also need to do the same in ADB2C app settings

Comment: As I can see that your callback path there is not /customer/index

Comment: Same issue. Any way to handle this? I'm trying this with a Razor pages project and cannot see any clear instructions on how to work with this or the Account 'area' it sets up

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source at: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Azure/AzureAD/Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/src/Areas/AzureADB2C/Controllers/AccountController.cs

**Their Default Implementation**

```
    [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
    public IActionResult SignIn([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
        scheme = scheme ?? AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
            scheme);
    }
```

You can see how they are hardcoding the redirect Url to the root of your site. Implement your own controller method that accepts the redirect path and use your new controller over the built in controller.

**A Naive Implementation Supporting a Passed in Redirect**

```
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public IActionResult Login([FromQuery] string dest)
    {
        var scheme = "AzureADB2C";
        var redirectUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dest) ? Url.Content("~/") : Url.Content("~" + dest);
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
            scheme);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback path should be the path where your user lands after sign in, and should match to the callback path registered in AD application settings.

Now, I have never tried to use relative paths like in your case /customer/index.
I always used full path as previously explained and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didn't work out. I set the callback path on Azure and on my app --- First I tried to set the full path on both but I got the following error: 
https://i.ibb.co/tx7BFmH/123123.png  --- Then I tried to set the full path on Azure and relative path /CreditApplication/Index on appsettings.json, the authentication worked but it did not redirect - it went straight to home aka https://localhost:44312/.

Comment: Instance property, can you please try to set: https://TenantName.b2clogin.com instead of login.microsoft as this will be deprecated: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/10/05/b2clogin-com-is-now-generally-available/

Comment: Btw also please check this exception that you have in a screenshot. That exception refers to other problem and is not related to b2c according to stackoverflow.

Comment: The exception only happens when I switch the CallbackPath from /CreditApplication/Index to https://localhost:44312/CreditApplication/Index -- Any ideas? Could you perhaps share your appsettings.json?

Comment: I do not have the code as it belongs to the customer, but I remember that I used this repo as a reference, so please have a look at this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp

And Instance was not login.microsoft, it was tenant.b2clogin.com/tfp